How to resolve "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) ... "
Trying to display Cards (tailwindcss) in my NextJs App router application (pasted below). However, I merely copying and pasteing the code threw an error:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `SummaryComponentBox`.

What seemed to work in the past (with tailwindcss/nextjs) now throws an error. Please keep in mind that this is Default export as shown in the code. I noticed that many solutions online say to check how it was export/import. Can you spot why this issue persists, and how can I resolve it?
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  ArrowDownCircleIcon,
  ArrowPathIcon,
  ArrowUpCircleIcon,
  EllipsisHorizontalIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import { Menu, MenuButton, MenuItem, MenuItems } from "@headlessui/react";

const SummaryComponentBox = () => {
  const [showSummary, setShowSummary] = useState(true);
  const clients = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Tuple",
      imageUrl: "https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/48x48/tuple.svg",
      lastInvoice: {
        date: "December 13, 2022",
        dateTime: "2022-12-13",
        amount: "$2,000.00",
        status: "Overdue",
      },
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "SavvyCal",
      imageUrl: "https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/48x48/savvycal.svg",
      lastInvoice: {
        date: "January 22, 2023",
        dateTime: "2023-01-22",
        amount: "$14,000.00",
        status: "Paid",
      },
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Reform",
      imageUrl: "https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/48x48/reform.svg",
      lastInvoice: {
        date: "January 23, 2023",
        dateTime: "2023-01-23",
        amount: "$7,600.00",
        status: "Paid",
      },
    },
  ];

  function classNames(...classes) {
    return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
  }

  return (
    <>
      {showSummary ? (
        <>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 justify-center items-center">
            <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
              <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl lg:mx-0 lg:max-w-none">
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                  <h2 className="text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900">
                    Recent clients
                  </h2>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
                  >
                    View all<span className="sr-only">, clients</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <ul
                  role="list"
                  className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:gap-x-8"
                >
                  {clients.map((client) => (
                    <li
                      key={client.id}
                      className="overflow-hidden rounded-xl border border-gray-200"
                    >
                      <div className="flex items-center gap-x-4 border-b border-gray-900/5 bg-gray-50 p-6">
                        <img
                          src={client.imageUrl}
                          alt={client.name}
                          className="h-12 w-12 flex-none rounded-lg bg-white object-cover ring-1 ring-gray-900/10"
                        />
                        <div className="text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
                          {client.name}
                        </div>
                        <Menu as="div" className="relative ml-auto">
                          <MenuButton className="-m-2.5 block p-2.5 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
                            <span className="sr-only">Open options</span>
                            <EllipsisHorizontalIcon
                              className="h-5 w-5"
                              aria-hidden="true"
                            />
                          </MenuButton>
                          <MenuItems
                            transition
                            className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-0.5 w-32 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-2 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 transition focus:outline-none data-[closed]:scale-95 data-[closed]:transform data-[closed]:opacity-0 data-[enter]:duration-100 data-[leave]:duration-75 data-[enter]:ease-out data-[leave]:ease-in"
                          >
                            <MenuItem>
                              {({ focus }) => (
                                <a
                                  href="#"
                                  className={classNames(
                                    focus ? "bg-gray-50" : "",
                                    "block px-3 py-1 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-900"
                                  )}
                                >
                                  View
                                  <span className="sr-only">
                                    , {client.name}
                                  </span>
                                </a>
                              )}
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem>
                              {({ focus }) => (
                                <a
                                  href="#"
                                  className={classNames(
                                    focus ? "bg-gray-50" : "",
                                    "block px-3 py-1 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-900"
                                  )}
                                >
                                  Edit
                                  <span className="sr-only">
                                    , {client.name}
                                  </span>
                                </a>
                              )}
                            </MenuItem>
                          </MenuItems>
                        </Menu>
                      </div>
                      <dl className="-my-3 divide-y divide-gray-100 px-6 py-4 text-sm leading-6">
                        <div className="flex justify-between gap-x-4 py-3">
                          <dt className="text-gray-500">Last invoice</dt>
                          <dd className="text-gray-700">
                            <time dateTime={client.lastInvoice.dateTime}>
                              {client.lastInvoice.date}
                            </time>
                          </dd>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex justify-between gap-x-4 py-3">
                          <dt className="text-gray-500">Amount</dt>
                          <dd className="flex items-start gap-x-2">
                            <div className="font-medium text-gray-900">
                              {client.lastInvoice.amount}
                            </div>
                            <div
                              className={classNames(
                                statuses[client.lastInvoice.status],
                                "rounded-md px-2 py-1 text-xs font-medium ring-1 ring-inset"
                              )}
                            >
                              {client.lastInvoice.status}
                            </div>
                          </dd>
                        </div>
                      </dl>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        "You have no active campaign. Launch one today."
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default SummaryComponentBox;


have you verified the output of statuses[client.lastInvoice.status] ? statuses is not defined anywhere in your sample
